# CKAN page slows down when tracking is enabled

Tags: nginx, ckan

CKAN is running on version 2.9.1. When enabled ckan's native tracking, it is slowing down the page load. On the first hit it loads quickly but on the next hit, it takes about 90 seconds.

There is a reverse proxy Nginx. On it, I'm getting timeout error on the _tracking call.

> *99 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,

But on the application level, I had put in some print statements which are all getting printed(the call is reaching the CKAN application).

Answer (score 0):

Nginx was expecting a response from the application, but it wasn't responding. I've set the timeout for this at Nginx manually. Now there is no lag.

Comment: Hi, could you please indicate which timeout you set in Nginx to solve the issue?